# How do I tell maven-verifier-plugin to use a location inside an archive?

Tags: maven-2, maven-plugin

The [maven-verifier-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-verifier-plugin) seems useful, but the example verifications.xml:

```
<verifications><files>
<file>
  <location>src/main/resources/file1.txt</location>
</file>
<file>
  <location>src/main/resources/file2.txt</location>
  <contains>aaaabbbb</contains>
</file>
<file>
  <location>src/main/resources/file3.txt</location>
  <exists>false</exists>
</file>
```

is too simple.  I want to specify a location inside an archive (e.g., jar or zip) file.  How can I do that?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A look through the [source code](https://github.com/apache/maven-verifier-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/apache/maven/plugins/verifier/VerifierMojo.java) only shows files being opened using a [File](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html) object and File won't extract things from and archive.  So you won't be able to do this without modifying the plugin itself.

Comment: Thanks.  That's what I found, too.  It's a shame, though--would be much more useful if it supported this.